# What type is a "unsigned any_variable" variable belongs to ? whats its size?

Tags: c

Is it equivalent to a unsigned integer ?
I'm able to use unsigned unknown_type_var = 3332934;
and print it successfully. This value is greater than a integer variable right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unsigned is totally equivalent to unsigned int, just like long is equivalent to long int, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is same as `unsigned int`. By default the type is `int`.

The max value for `unsigned int` is `4294967295`. This limits are defined in the LIMITS.H header file. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fh3a000.aspx.

Comment: The blanket statement "The max value for unsigned int is 4294967295" is incorrect. It happens to be true on many platforms, but it does not make it true as stated. The C standard does not specify exact size of types.

Comment: The maximum value for an "int" is INT_MAX. The maxium value for an unsigned int is UINT_MAX. These constants can be found in the standard header <limits.h>.

Answer (score 0):

unsigned just means that it doesn't use the first bit as a sign (positive, negative) so it is always positive and has twice the capacity of a signed any_variable.

This stackoverflow question should help explain signed and unsigned variables in depth:
[What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc)

Most C implementations use 4 bytes for integers so that's a range between ~-2bil to ~2bil or 0 to 4bil for unsigned ints so your variable is well within the range of an interger.

Comment: but still it should have a type right like "unsigned int <var_name>",  "unsigned char <var_name>"  ?? I'm talking about just using a varibale declared as "unsigned <var_name>" !!!

Comment: ah i see what you mean, yes by default it means unsigned int as in Sachin's answer. misread your question

Comment: The size of int is implementation-defined. You can't know if its maximum value is 65k or 4bil.

Comment: @Lundin, that is technically correct but we are talking about C and in the context of the C variant of langauges most ints are defined in 32bits which has a value ~65k. of course some imps used to define them as half a word but i'd rather not talk about those...

Comment: @Joe. Huh? 32 bit unsigned integers have a value of ~4.29 bil. 16 bit unsigned integers have a value of ~65k. The default unsigned int type in C can be either, but a 32-bit int will *never* be 65k. And I don't believe the default "int" type is allowed to be unsigned to conform with the standard.

Comment: @Lundin, now i see what you were getting at in the first reply. 65k was just plain wrong, my bad. i thought it looked a bit small. i've changed my answer to be less incorrect :)